# Can XML Parsing Error be cause by new database column in table

Tags: java, html, xml, ajax, database

I was wondering can the following error on an `AJAX GET` request

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{e524cf00-ed0a-4e2b-925a-fcc995b9d682} Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

be cause by added a new column to a table in a database, as i cannot find out why i am getting this error and it is driving me crazy!?

[image]

Here is a **all** of what i get if i do not change the `ownershipType` field

```
<ajax-response>
<response id="licenceAuthRequiredDiv" type="element">
<div id="licenceAuthRequiredDiv">
<input id="licensingApprovalDateRequired" type="text" name="licensingApprovalDateRequired" value="" title="dd MMM yyyy">
<a href="javascript:calendar_licensingApprovalDateRequired.toggle(tapestry.byId("licensingApprovalDateRequired"));">
<img class="datePickerImg" src="/wuams/assets/static/org/apache/tapestry/form/DatePickerIcon.png" alt="Click on icon to choose a date/time value." border="0">
</a>
<span class="requiredStar">*</span>
</div>
</response>
<response id="initializationscript" type="script">
<script>
//
calendar_licensingApprovalDateRequired = new Calendar(); calendar_licensingApprovalDateRequired.initialize(["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"], ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"], ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"], ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"], "dd MMM yyyy", 1, false, 4, "Clear"); calendar_licensingApprovalDateRequired.onchange = function() { var field = tapestry.byId("form").licensingApprovalDateRequired; var value = calendar_licensingApprovalDateRequired.formatDate(); if (field.value != value) { field.value = value; if (field.onchange) { field.onchange();} } } dojo.require("tapestry.form"); tapestry.cleanConnect("licensingStatus", "onchange", "formEvent2107635243"); tapestry.formEvent2107635243=function(e){ var content={beventname:"onchange", bcomponentidpath:"EditCompanyPage/licensingStatus", bcomponentid:"licensingStatus"}; tapestry.event.buildEventProperties(e, content, arguments); if (!content["beventtarget.id"]){ content["beventtarget.id"]="licensingStatus"; } var validateState=tapestry.form.forms["form"].validateForm; var validateForm=false; tapestry.form.setFormValidating("form", validateForm); tapestry.form.submitAsync("form", content); tapestry.form.setFormValidating("form", validateState); }; tapestry.connect("licensingStatus", "onchange", "formEvent2107635243"); //
</script>
</response>
<response id="bodyscript" type="script">
<script>
//
var calendar_licensingApprovalDateRequired; dojo.require("tapestry.event"); //
</script>
</response>
<response id="includescript" type="script">
<include url="/wuams/assets/static/org/apache/tapestry/form/DatePicker.js"></include>
</response>
<response id="formhidden" type="element">
<div id="formhidden" style="display:none;">
<input type="hidden" name="formids" value="If_33,If_0_11,If_35,If_37,For_1_1,wuBusinessId,companyNameUK,tradingName,companyMultiplicity,If_39,ownershipType,autoSendToDueDiligence,businessType,If_0_13,parentCompany,address1,address2,address3,city,state,postCode,selectCountry,If_41,networkId,automaticRoaming,phoneNumber,emailAddress,faxNumber,keyContactFirstName,keyContactSurname,keyContactPhone,keyContactFaxNumber,keyContactEmail,mtLicenceNumber,regulatedEntity,licensingAuthority,regulator,licensingStatus,If_43,licensingApprovalDateRequired,registrationNumber,fitandProperInitiated,If_45,limitedCompanyRegistrationNumber,reportsDailyFileDirectory,selectCutOffPeriod,settlementDispersal,sarEmailAddress,groupFinancialLimit,If_47,creationDate,If_49,expiryDate,preContractCompliance,gddSignOffDate,amlSignOffDate,save">
<input type="hidden" name="seedids" value="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">
<input type="hidden" name="submitmode" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="submitname" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="If_33" value="F">
<input type="hidden" name="If_0_11" value="F">
<input type="hidden" name="If_35" value="F">
<input type="hidden" name="If_37" value="T">
<input type="hidden" name="For_1_1" value="VSInvalid data in Company details:">
<input type="hidden" name="For_1_1" value="VSOwnership Type is mandatory.">
<input type="hidden" name="If_39" value="F">
<input type="hidden" name="If_0_13" value="T">
<input type="hidden" name="If_41" value="T">
<input type="hidden" name="If_43" value="T">
<input type="hidden" name="If_45" value="F">
<input type="hidden" name="If_47" value="T">
<input type="hidden" name="If_49" value="T">
</div>
</response>
</ajax-response>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the content to be sure `Location` is a tag?

Comment: I don't have any `Location` tags  in my code

Comment: Can you post what the first 2 or 3 lines of your content contains? The error suggests its not XML.

Comment: Well i am using Firebug to try find out what is going on but when i go into the XML tag because the GET request is hanging, all it says is the error above, no more information

Comment: So there is not way to know if its even XML you are getting?

Comment: well the thing is the request works if i do not enter any data into a field `Type`, the above edit is the code that the GET request returns and everything works perfectly, but if i add anything into this `Type` field i get the XML Parser Error

Comment: But you couldn't tell if the setting the type makes it produce JSon instead of XML for example?

Comment: to do this call i have an event listener on licensingStatus, the name of the type that is causing the error is `ownershipType` which is mentioned in the ajax response above, it is when this is changed that is when the problem is occuring

Comment: to answer your question above, i do not know if ownershipType is producing Json or XML :/